# Playing Audio parse - Ambiguous use of 'url' Xcode 7.1 - swift2.0

Tags: url, audio, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

Xcode 7.1 - swift2.0 - parse.com

getting error :

> Ambiguous use of 'url'

```
if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.valueForKey("SongFile")?.url {  

           player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
        player.play()

        }
```

please advise

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use NSURL or string conversions. Access the `PFFile` url directly like so

```
if let songFile: PFFile = object?.valueForKey("SongFile") as? PFFile {
    player = AVPlayer(URL: songFile.url!)
    player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, this is the function that I used for swift 2

func GetSongFromParse(){

```
    let querySongs = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    querySongs.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects{

            for object in objects{

                self.iDArray.append(object.valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
                self.songNamesArray.append(object["SongName"] as! String)
                self.songFileArray.append(object["SongFile"] as! PFFile)

            }
        }

        print(self.songFileArray[0])
        print(self.songNamesArray[0])
        print(self.iDArray)


        if let url = NSURL(string: self.songFileArray[0].url!){


        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)   
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aaron for below solution

```
func grabSong(){
    let SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "songs")
    SongQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block:{

        (object: PFObject?, error:NSError?)-> Void in

        if let songFile: PFFile = object?.valueForKey("songFile") as? PFFile {
            AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: songFile.url)
            AudioPlayer.play()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 the **url** parameter is with lowercase, this solved the issue for me.

```
player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
```